# Do While loop hangs

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

The loop below hangs if the input fufills the Do...While condition.

1. This code is meant to first check if the entered product code in the combobox (Me!Combo_Product_number) exists in product code field of query Q_compliant_FCM_EU.
2. If it exists, it tests for compliance. The product is compliant if all its PURE_QP1 (which can be more than one for a particular product) is found in PURE_QP1 field of T_DOSSIER_FPL. 
   If at least one of them is not found, then it is not compliant.

```
Private Sub Command455_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim rst1 As Recordset

If Nz(Me!Combo_Product_number) <> "" Then
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Q_compliant_FCM_EU", dbOpenDynaset)
   Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset("T_DOSSIER_FPL", dbOpenDynaset)

   rst.FindFirst "[PRODUCT_CODE] = '" & Me!Combo_Product_number & "'"
   If Not rst.NoMatch Then

       Do While Not rst1.EOF

        rst1.FindFirst "[PURE_QP1] = '" & rst.Fields("PURE_QP1") & "'"

        If Not rst1.NoMatch Then
            rst1.MoveNext
        Else
            MsgBox ("Product code is NOT compliant to FPL")
            Exit Sub
        End If

       Loop

       MsgBox ("Product code is compliant to FPL")

   Else
       MsgBox ("Product code is not available")
   End If

End If

End Sub
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *DLookup* for such simple tasks, like:

```vb
Dim PURE_QP1 As Variant

If Nz(Me!Combo_Product_number) <> "" Then

    PURE_QP1 = DLookup("[PURE_QP1]", "[Q_compliant_FCM_EU]", "[PRODUCT_CODE] = '" & Me!Combo_Product_number & "'")
    If IsNull(PURE_QP1) Then
        MsgBox ("Product code is not available")
    Else
        If IsNull(DLookup("[ID field of T_DOSSIER_FPL]", "[T_DOSSIER_FPL]", "[PURE_QP1] = '" & PURE_QP1 & "'")
            MsgBox ("Product code is NOT compliant to FPL")
        End If
    End If

End If
```

Comment: DCount could also be used. I was composing similar answer when Gustav posted.

Comment: there is syntax error in `  IsNull(DLookup("[ID field of T_DOSSIER_FPL]", "[T_DOSSIER_FPL]", "[PURE_QP1] = '"   ` Also, do i need to open the recordset for the table to be regonisable?

Comment: Sure. Insert a field name of yours. We don't know about them.